# Disable debug output in Gogland

Tags: go, goland

After updating to the last Gogland release in my debug console I see such information

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
GOPATH=/Users/mayvas/GoProjects
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/m5/gqb1s0q579b6bdz7hdjwmf7r0000gn/T/___go_run_addressbook_go /Users/mayvas/GoProjects/src/gitlab.yarmel.com/mayvas/meafex/addressbook.go
/private/var/folders/m5/gqb1s0q579b6bdz7hdjwmf7r0000gn/T/___go_run_addressbook_go
```

It is possible to disable this? I use small screen resolution & this info  not useful for me.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Help | Find Action...
2. Type Registry and hit Enter.
3. Find go.run.processes.with.pty there and turn it off.

Now IDE will **`fold`** those information and will make it look cleaner.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 3):

Until the issue that @dlsniper mentioned got fixed, you can use following workaround:

Add `GOPATH=`, `GOROOT=`, etc. as a code folding marker in `File | Settings | Editor | General | Console`. Like this:

[image: Code folding settings]

After that output will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> After updating to the last Gogland release in my debug console I see such information

The latest version added just the GOROOT line, all other information was there before.

> It is possible to disable this? I use small screen resolution & this info not useful for me.

At the moment you cannot hide / disable that information, you can only clear the console. However it looks like you've disabled the `Scroll to end` option, the button right above the `Print` in the run window. That should hide the output automatically for you by scrolling the view whenever the output vertical length is bigger than what the console size is.

I've filled https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4452 for you, please watch the issue there for updates